# Stored procedure to delete the 4 large table records in small chunks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

As I am new to procedures, I request your help on below pls.

There is a requirement to delete the records from a large table in small chunks like 10 Million records at a time.

For example, if you have 1000 days records in a table then you need to delete in small chunks like 10M at once. first will select 100 days records if it is below 10 Million then it will delete or else it will split into 50-50 days, like the same way I need to reduce from 1000 days to 50 days.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT;
    SELECT 
        @ROWCOUNT = count(*)
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
        timestamp>=GETDATE()-1000 and timestamp<=GETDATE()-900;
    SELECT @ROWCOUNT;
    IF @ROWCOUNT < 10000000
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM table where timestamp>=GETDATE()-1000 and timestamp<=GETDATE()-900;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'The data is more than the 10M records for the selected 100 days, you need to split into 50-50days';
    END
END
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide the table definition please?

Comment: [Take Care When Scripting Batches](https://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/)